# Java opencsv mapping - undefined number of fields

Tags: java, csv

I write applications in Java, which will operate on a csv file. Will be responsible for the selected date range count data in columns (col1, col2).

```
2014-23-11;22;22;22;23;4;4;5;
2014-23-11;32;22;22;23;4;4;5;
2014-23-11;62;52;22;23;4;4;5;
2014-23-11;28;22;22;93;4;4;5;
```

Other file

```
2014-23-11;22;22;22;23;4;4;5;;543;456646;45
2014-23-11;32;22;22;23;4;4;5;;4564;6456;5;5
2014-23-11;62;52;22;23;4;4;5;;4564;5645645;4
2014-23-11;28;22;22;93;4;4;5;456;456;456;456
```

I want the application to be independent from csv files. Eg. One file will have 10 fields, and the other 20. The field of the date will always be at the beginning. How can I prepare for the mapping of the predetermined number of fields in a file?

Comment: Create a bean that has a `Date` and a `List<Number>`. Read the line into the bean. Profit.

Comment: ok, but how do I create a field in the class if I do not know in advance how many file will have fields

Comment: Because it wants to map data using Java Beans, as is for example: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-csv-file/ unless it is unnecessary

Comment: Obviously you cannot use the default mapper as that maps fields to bean properties - this is not what you have here. You can very easily implement a custom mapper.

Comment: You can clearly? How would you do it?

Comment: Write some code. Make some effort. Post your attempt and where you got stuck. This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: I know it, but I still do not know how to hold the data. Keeping them in the class is a bad idea?

Comment: How to generate class fields based on a csv file?

Comment: I decided to keep everything in the map `Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();`
, the names of the columns that appear in the first line will be the key, but I wonder how it read with opencsv, is there any method that reads the entire column?

Comment: I found something http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-csv-file/. Just as I do to read all of the columns and the first row of columns is the key